# Losing ajax data in Express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Node/Express app that has an authorized user logged in. I then have that user make an ajax call with data to a protected route. I have middleware making sure the user is authenticated before continuing to the route. The data is lost between the ajax call and then hitting the route. Is there a way to preserve the data from being lost in this middleware?

Front end .js file

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/voted",
  method: "POST",
  data: { item1: "some data", item2: "other data" },
  success: () => { console.log("success") },
  failure: () => { console.log("failure") }
});
```

middleware for the route

```
// data being lost here
const protectedMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  }
  else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

route in my routes.js file

```
app.post("/voted", protectedMiddleware, (req, res) => {

  let item1 = req.query.item1;
  let item2 = req.query.item2;
  console.log(item1); // undefined
  console.log(item2); // undefined

});
```

For item1 and item2, I'm getting undefined, whereas they should be "some data" and "other data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.query` is set from the query parameters in the url. So, `req.query.item1` would be accessible if the request url looked like `/voted?item1=somedata`.

What you are looking for is `req.body`, since you are passing your data in the `body` of the request.

You can access `item1` and `item2` as `req.body.item1` and `req.body.item2`